# APEX Trigger Not updating numbers on Custom filed Callable_Contacts__c on Account after addition or deletion

Tags: apex

My trigger is as follows:

```
trigger AccountCallableContact on Contact (after insert, after delete) {
    SET<ID> contId = new SET<ID>();    
    LIST<Account> accountPhonePopulated = new LIST<Account>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        if(Trigger.isAfter) {
            for(Contact newContact : Trigger.new) {                
                if(newContact.Phone != NULL) {
                   contId.add(newContact.AccountId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

            if(Trigger.isDelete) {
                if(Trigger.isAfter) {
                    for(Contact delContact : Trigger.old) {
                        if(delContact.Phone != NULL) {                          
                        contId.add(delContact.AccountId);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

            LIST<Account> updateAccount = new LIST<Account>([SELECT ID, Name, Callable_Contacts__c, 
                                                             (SELECT ID, Name FROM Contacts WHERE Phone != NULL)
                                           FROM Account WHERE ID IN :contId]);
           system.debug('total' + updateAccount);            
           LIST<Contact> totalCount = [SELECT ID
                                        FROM Contact
                                        WHERE (Phone != NULL AND ID IN :contId)];      
            for(Account finalUpdateAccount :updateAccount) {
                //LIST<Contact> numContact = finalUpdateAccount.Contacts;                
                finalUpdateAccount.Callable_Contacts__c = totalCount.size();
                accountPhonePopulated.add(finalUpdateAccount);

            }            

        if(accountPhonePopulated.size() > 0) {
        update accountPhonePopulated;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger has several issues with regard to best practices and logic that I will skip for now, but the main problem you find is in this part of your code.

```
    WHERE (Phone != NULL AND ID IN :contId))];
```

Confusingly, you are populating `contId` with the `AccountId` property of the records you iterate. Therefore, the list `contId` will never contain Ids for the `Contact` object.

Regardless, if you change the update to

```
finalUpdateAccount.Callable_Contacts__c = finalUpdateAccount.Contacts.size();
```

You should obtain what you want, and the select statement in question should be moot and can be deleted.

Also, the line `accountPhonePopulated.add(finalUpdateAccount);` is unnecessary if you change `update accountPhonePopulated;` to `update updateAccount;`